# SingleInstance and Home button navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, android-manifest, single-instance

I have a problem of navigation.

I have three activity A, B and C.

I'm making an application to play music. So I need a persistent activity that run in background for that contain the controll of the mediaplayer.

So, I want the activity `C` to be always running. 
So I configured the activity `C` like this :

```
<activity
   android:launchMode="singleInstance"
   android:name="ch.etml.podcast.PlayerActivity" >
</activity>
```

My problem is when I navigate like in this order `B -> C -> HOME PRESS -> Click on application icon` the activity `B` is launched instead of the activity `C`.

After reading several questions I have understand that it seems to be a normal behavior when using lauchmod `singleInstance`.
How can I solve this problem ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

`singleInstance` is not a good choice. Your activity C is run in a separate task. When you try to launch app, after pressing HOME, the task of your main activity is restored which does not include C.

I would give you advice what to do but I don't really understand what you trying to achieve for your music player. Can you explain it in more details?

**Update**

If you are developing app with media player running in the background, have a look at the sample app in SDK samples e.g. [sdk folder]/samples/android-19/legacy/RandomMediaPlayer

It's a great base code for your own app.

Comment: The activity C is the activity that read all the media that has been clicked in activity B. When I'm clicking on a song from activity B i want the activity C to be bring to front

Comment: OK, but why does it have to be singleInstance. Can you give me an example which you tried to solve with this property? If you don't set this property activity C will not be shown when you start the app from initial state and if C is visible and you press HOME it will be bring to front. What am I missing?

Comment: The music need to be play even when the application is in background. When I click on a song in activity B, I want to reuse the connection with the service from Activity C to change the song, i don't want to recreate the whole activity

Comment: I would expect activity C to be a thin client for your music service. If C does some heavy loading every time you create it then you should consider refactoring. When C is created you should just establish connection to music service and show what is playing. This way you can go from B to C and back any times you want. When B starts C you just pass song identifier and in C creation, after establishing connection with the service, change playing song. If it's not suitable for you please post some code of yours. I have created app with media playing in the background and it works for me perfect.

Comment: This sounds like a design issue, not programming. There is no single answer. Your options are limited by your imagination. One popular solutions would be creating notification controlled by your music service. From that notification you can launch activity C. You can also structure your UI differently. Maybe instead activities use fragments within tabs, spinner or navigation drawer. In that case you could have just one activity which is always connected to music service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52103/discussion-between-loop-and-timothy-t)